# Convert row to column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to convert dict to html table, but not able to figure out, how to convert row to column in this case?

```
import pandas as pd

c = {'result': 'FAIL', "LinkA": "https:// example.com/dwdewdbeuwwuvdwudwufdqwdqqdqdqdqwedeuq.txt",
     "NDT": "https://example.com/dgwuydweufdwuefgwfwfdwefef.txt",
     "KKT": "https:// example.com/fewnewvbbcuwecvwxvwwecewc.txt"}
c = {k:[v] for k,v in c.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(c)
df.to_html("/tmp/a1.html")
```

Actual Output:
[image: Actual Output]

Required Output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: You could just transpose the dataframe with `df = pd.DataFrame(c).T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change how you create the `df` using [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

c = {'result': 'FAIL', "LinkA": "https:// example.com/dwdewdbeuwwuvdwudwufdqwdqqdqdqdqwedeuq.txt",
     "NDT": "https://example.com/dgwuydweufdwuefgwfwfdwefef.txt",
     "KKT": "https:// example.com/fewnewvbbcuwecvwxvwwecewc.txt"}
c = {k:[v] for k,v in c.items()}

# orient here
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index')

df.to_html("tmp/a1.html")
```

Out
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try pivot and transpose

```
data="""result,fail
LinkA,1
NDT,2
KKT,3
LinkA,4
NDT,5
KKT,6
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=",")
df.columns=columns=["result","fail"]
#print(df.T)
df = df.pivot(index="result", columns="fail", values="fail")
print(df.T)
```

output

```
result  KKT  LinkA  NDT
fail                   
1       NaN    1.0  NaN
2       NaN    NaN  2.0
3       3.0    NaN  NaN
4       NaN    4.0  NaN
5       NaN    NaN  5.0
6       6.0    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Series on the original dictionary:

```
pd.Series(c).reset_index().to_html()
```

Variants:

```
pd.Series(c).reset_index(name='value').to_html()
```

```
pd.Series(c).reset_index().to_html(header=False, index=False)
```